# How to secure insert statements in wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress and I have done quite a bit of reading on how to insert data into the database with prepared statements.
My question is how secure is this code?:

```
    $wpdb->query(
     $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}tablename(id,custom_field) 
        VALUES(%d, %s)",$ID, $customfield)
    );
```

Is there anything else I could do to secure this code?
I know is probably a silly question but I would like to know how to it properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd have to recheck the docs regarding $wpdb, but seems legit. Anyway why don't you use `update_post_meta` (as it is fully secured)?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format )`.
Usage:

```
$wpdb->insert( 
'table', 
array( 
    'column1' => 'value1', 
    'column2' => 123 
), 
array( 
    '%s', 
    '%d' 
)
```

);

More info in: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows